# Power regulation circuits on B+ vs 2 (light sensitivity)

Tags: hardware, power-management, pi-2, pi-models

I've seen recent articles on the Raspberry Pi 2 being affected by a light source (http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=99042) . Apparently the cause is in the power regulation circuit of the Pi.

Does the Pi B+ have the same problem, or is the circuit sufficiently different that it does not have the affected component?

Comment: First I've heard of this.  I have not seen it mentioned on the raspberrypi.org forums.  Have you a source?

Comment: @joan: http://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=28&t=99042 . I will add it to the question

Comment: I didn't read that thread as I thought it was a joke (because of the title).  I have just skimmed through. My PI 2 locked up when I took a flash photo.  A B+ was unaffected.

Comment: Wow.  Guess that got skipped in QC.  I've noticed a B and a B+ that would often reset an I2C device the moment something was unplugged on the same (household) circuit.

Comment: All semiconductors are light sensitive. (I discovered this the hard way - more than 50 years ago when I scraped the paint off my 1st transistor - in those days transistors were in little glass tubes). The encapsulation keeps light away, but surface mount components are not designed to be exposed to the environment.

Comment: Maybe there is a solution: http://www.krylon.com/products/premium-metallic/

Answer (score 2):

According to the Raspberry Pi Foundation, the problem lies with component U16 in the power supply.  This is not a component used on previous models.

The explanation is given [here](http://www.raspberrypi.org/xenon-death-flash-a-free-physics-lesson/).

This also explains that the problem is a photoelectric effect caused by specific long light wavelengths, particularly Xenon camera flash guns.  So other light sources have no effect.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't consider this authoritative but the following article suggests it is "light" sensitive and not EMF as I had originally thought. Previous models are not affected.

http://arstechnica.com/security/2015/02/just-released-raspberry-pi-2-can-be-dosed-by-bright-flashes-of-light/

Comment: but why are previous models not affected? Component types? Circuit changes?