# Raspberry Pi2 crashing when running camera (streaming video)

Tags: raspbian, motion

Running headless with:
Linux weatherpi 3.18.11-v7+ #781 SMP PREEMPT Tue Apr 21 18:07:59 BST 2015 armv7l GNU/Linux

I am using the raspberry camera module.

I can stream video, I've tried both motion (not mmal, std motion), which works "out of the box" and uv4l-webrtc (Thank you ppumkin), which also works "out of the box".

However, both of these solutions seem to crash my P2. Mostly with bright light, although that's just a guess based on un-scientific observation. It runs anywhere from 30 secs to 20 hours without fail. Then it causes a reboot. Doesn't seem to matter if I'm streaming at the time or not. I've tried running motion with -d 9 but that doesn't give me anything useful. Below is the syslog from a recent failure. Seems to be a network issue but that doesn't make sense because it only happens if motion or uv4l-webrtc are running, regardless of if they are streaming at the time. Using USB wireless dongle (WIPI). Wondering if there might be an issue in conflict between the bus taking the camera images and the USB bus??

Note: Power supply is 5V 2amp and it's never had an issue before but I'm open to trying another if someone suggests it. I've ordered another camera module to test but it's still on the way. Any suggestions on what the issue is or how to get more info to debug would be helpful.

```
May 12 10:14:37 weatherpi kernel: [63914.576521] wlan0: AP 64:66:b3:90:73:36 changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 1 (2462/0 MHz)
May 12 10:14:38 weatherpi kernel: [63915.600522] wlan0: AP 64:66:b3:90:73:36 changed bandwidth, new config is 2462 MHz, width 2 (2452/0 MHz)
May 12 10:17:01 weatherpi /USR/SBIN/CRON[3584]: (root) CMD (   cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly)
May 12 10:18:53 weatherpi kernel: [64170.913294] fuse init (API version 7.23)
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.394074] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_tx_sta_fifo_read_completed: Warning - TX status read failed -71
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.394292] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_tx_sta_fifo_read_completed: Warning - TX status read failed -71
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.394536] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_tx_sta_fifo_read_completed: Warning - TX status read failed -71
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.394844] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_tx_sta_fifo_read_completed: Warning - TX status read failed -71
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.395344] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.395344]
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.396051] ieee80211 phy0: rt2800usb_tx_sta_fifo_read_completed: Warning - TX status read failed -108
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.396086] ERROR::dwc_otg_hcd_urb_enqueue:505: Not connected
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.396086]
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi avahi-daemon[2359]: Withdrawing workstation service for eth0.
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.411286] usb 1-1: USB disconnect, device number 2
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.411331] usb 1-1.1: USB disconnect, device number 3
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.411780] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: unregister 'smsc95xx' usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethernet
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.411891] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.468026] usb 1-1.4: USB disconnect, device number 4
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi wpa_supplicant[1657]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-DISCONNECTED bssid=64:66:b3:90:73:36 reason=3
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi avahi-daemon[2359]: Interface wlan0.IPv4 no longer relevant for mDNS.
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi avahi-daemon[2359]: Leaving mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.221.
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.581055] wlan0: deauthenticating from 64:66:b3:90:73:36 by local choice (Reason: 3=DEAUTH_LEAVING)
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi avahi-daemon[2359]: IP_DROP_MEMBERSHIP failed: No such device
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi avahi-daemon[2359]: Withdrawing address record for 192.168.0.221 on wlan0.
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi avahi-daemon[2359]: Withdrawing workstation service for wlan0.
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.646179] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: US
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi ifplugd(eth0)[1682]: Exiting.
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64473.941110] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00021501
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi ifplugd(wlan0)[1591]: Link beat lost.
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi wpa_supplicant[1657]: wlan0: Failed to initiate AP scan
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi ifplugd(wlan0)[1591]: Exiting.
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64474.153835] usb 1-1: new high-speed USB device number 5 using dwc_otg
May 12 10:23:56 weatherpi kernel: [64474.154479] Indeed it is in host mode hprt0 = 00001101
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.451411] usb 1-1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=9514
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.451443] usb 1-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.452544] hub 1-1:1.0: USB hub found
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.452717] hub 1-1:1.0: 5 ports detected
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.731412] usb 1-1.1: new high-speed USB device number 6 using dwc_otgMay 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.832250] usb 1-1.1: New USB device found, idVendor=0424, idProduct=ec00May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.832284] usb 1-1.1: New USB device strings: Mfr=0, Product=0, SerialNumber=0
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.836023] smsc95xx v1.0.4
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.900007] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: register 'smsc95xx' at usb-bcm2708_usb-1.1, smsc95xx USB 2.0 Ethern
et, b8:27:eb:be:c4:df
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64474.991254] usb 1-1.4: new high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi ifplugd(eth0)[4667]: ifplugd 0.28 initializing.
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi ifplugd(eth0)[4667]: Using interface eth0/B8:27:EB:BE:C4:DF with driver  (version: 22-Aug-2005)
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi ifplugd(eth0)[4667]: Using detection mode: SIOCETHTOOL
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi ifplugd(eth0)[4667]: Initialization complete, link beat not detected.
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64475.107012] smsc95xx 1-1.1:1.0 eth0: hardware isn't capable of remote wakeup
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64475.112358] usb 1-1.4: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=5370
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64475.112393] usb 1-1.4: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64475.112411] usb 1-1.4: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64475.112427] usb 1-1.4: Manufacturer: Ralink
May 12 10:23:57 weatherpi kernel: [64475.112443] usb 1-1.4: SerialNumber: 1.0
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi kernel: [64475.191182] usb 1-1.4: reset high-speed USB device number 7 using dwc_otg
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi kernel: [64475.302406] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 5390, rev 0502 detected
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi kernel: [64475.325579] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 5370 detected
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi kernel: [64475.326612] ieee80211 phy1: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi kernel: [64475.328672] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi kernel: [64475.329122] ieee80211 phy1: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.29
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi ifplugd(wlan0)[4688]: ifplugd 0.28 initializing.
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi ifplugd(wlan0)[4688]: Using interface wlan0/00:0F:13:28:12:B8 with driver  (version: 3.18.11-v7+)
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi ifplugd(wlan0)[4688]: Using detection mode: SIOCETHTOOL
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi ifplugd(wlan0)[4688]: Initialization complete, link beat not detected.
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi wpa_supplicant[4702]: ctrl_iface exists and seems to be in use - cannot override it
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi wpa_supplicant[4702]: Delete '/var/run/wpa_supplicant/wlan0' manually if it is not used anymore
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi wpa_supplicant[4702]: Failed to initialize control interface '/var/run/wpa_supplicant'.#012You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was#012left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need#012to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
May 12 10:23:58 weatherpi wpa_supplicant[1657]: wlan0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING - signal 15 received
May 12 10:23:59 weatherpi avahi-daemon[2359]: Joining mDNS multicast group on interface wlan0.IPv4 with address 192.168.0.221.
May 12 10:23:59 weatherpi avahi-daemon[2359]: New relevant interface wlan0.IPv4 for mDNS.
May 12 10:23:59 weatherpi avahi-daemon[2359]: Registering new address record for 192.168.0.221 on wlan0.IPv4.
May 12 10:24:06 weatherpi watchdog[2423]: device wlan0 did not receive anything since last check
May 12 10:24:06 weatherpi watchdog[2423]: /usr/lib/sendmail does not exist or is not executable (errno = 2)
May 12 10:24:06 weatherpi watchdog[2423]: shutting down the system because of error 101
May 12 10:24:16 weatherpi kernel: [64493.332189] wdt: WDT device closed unexpectedly.  WDT will not stop!
May 12 10:24:16 weatherpi ifplugd(wlan0)[4688]: Exiting.
May 12 10:17:11 weatherpi kernel: imklog 5.8.11, log source = /proc/kmsg started.
May 12 10:17:11 weatherpi rsyslogd: [origin software="rsyslogd" swVersion="5.8.11" x-pid="2090" x-info="http://www.rsyslog.com"] start
May 12 10:17:11 weatherpi kernel: [    0.000000] Booting Linux on physical CPU 0xf00
```

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/202988/error-codes-for-watchdog-daemon If I were you, I'd either do some reading about configuring watchdog or else `update-rc.d disable watchdog`.

Comment: *"to crash my P2. Mostly with bright light"* -> Evidently not the cause in this particular case but something to be aware of: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/27444/power-regulation-circuits-on-b-vs-2-light-sensitivity

Comment: I actually added watchdog because the system would become inaccessible - not sure if it froze or just the network wasn't working. Watchdog saved me tons of time going back and forth unplugging the device. It's working as I wanted - if the network goes down it reboots. My issue is that the network seems to keep going down, but only when the camera is running.

Comment: Re: the light issue. Pi is in a waterproof box, camera looks out through glass. So light on the actual circuits should not be an issue, plus it's only the sun.

Comment: WRT staying connected you could try something like this: http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/4120/how-to-automatically-reconnect-wifi Kind of a hack solution which may or may not work in this case.

Comment: I did not notice the bit about `wpa_supplicant` failing earlier -- that seems to be the root cause of the problem.  I've edited something into my answer about that.

Comment: Very interesting. Try and put the Pi in a solid colour housing, which wont let light through to the PCB. Also try, just for arguments sake, with LAN instead of WiFi. WiFi always, and still is the bane of my life with the Pi and video streaming.(except running of batteries, there must be some interference with the generic USB chargers- Possibly using a nice regulated/swithcing power supply will solve allot of headaches)

Comment: Ha - It's in a grey box - no light getting in other than for the camera and light sensor. Nothing gets to the pi itself. Box is actually waterproof. Working on getting a cable to it but it may take a while to run it where the box is.

Comment: Is the case blocking the Wifi Signal? You might be losing signal through the case and that might be why the Wifi is flaking out.

Comment: It could be that the FCC of the camera is too close to the WiFi antenna: that would explain why connectivity issues only appear when the camera is active.

Answer (score 2):

```
watchdog[2423]: device wlan0 did not receive anything since last check
watchdog[2423]: shutting down the system because of error 101
```

Perhaps not the most user friendly documentation for `watchdog`, but there is this note in `man watchdog`.

> An positive exit code is interpreted as an system error code (see errno.h for details).

Presuming that "error 101" is also the exit code of the binary, we can find this in `/usr/include/asm-generic/errno.h`:

```
#define EADDRNOTAVAIL   99      /* Cannot assign requested address */
#define ENETDOWN        100     /* Network is down */
#define ENETUNREACH     101     /* Network is unreachable */
#define ENETRESET       102     /* Network dropped connection because of reset */
```

Which makes sense in this case, since the previous message was about wlan0 not receiving anything.

Whether you actually want that to happen is up to you; it's certainly not necessary.  I presume this is not a mandatory feature of `watchdog` either, so you'll have to either figure out how to configure it differently or else stop using it completely.

---

The reason your network is failing is evidently this:

```
wpa_supplicant[4702]: Failed to initialize control interface '/var/run/wpa_supplicant'.#012You may have another wpa_supplicant process already running or the file was#012left by an unclean termination of wpa_supplicant in which case you will need#012to manually remove this file before starting wpa_supplicant again.
```

Presuming your `/var/run` is the default `tmpfs` used on Raspbian, that cannot have been left, e.g., from a previous crash.  If you look back through the logs and determine this is consistently the root of the problem, you need to do something about it.  Possibly this could be done with a one of the network scripts, or you could ditch those and arrange something yourself.

Comment: I find `wicdcurses` to work really well with WiFi reconnecting problems. Good advice with watch dog though!